# IComparable<T> Inheritance or Interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

In below example, IComparable method CompareTo is used as a base method as far as I understood. I wonder isn't it compulsory to implement Interface method (CompareTo) in the class? Below example did not do this. Just used it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
public class MyClass<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public void GetBiggerValue(T Value1, T Value2)
    {
        if (Value1.CompareTo(Value2) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is bigger than {1}", Value1, Value2);
        }

        if (Value1.CompareTo(Value2) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is equal to {1}", Value1, Value2);
        }

        if (Value1.CompareTo(Value2) < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is smaller than {1}", Value1, Value2);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();

        MyClass<int> mcInt = new MyClass<int>();
        MyClass<string> mcString = new MyClass<string>();

        mcInt.GetBiggerValue(124, 126);             //126          

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Side note: check `Value1` for `null`

Comment: It is `T`, but not `MyClass<T>` must implment `IComparable<T>`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Your `MyClass` class is declaring that it can work, provided that it's instantiated with *some other type* that promises to implement `IComparable`. Well, both `int` and `string` do fulfil that promise.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `where T : IComparable<T>` implies a generic class where `T` must implement `IComparable<T>`. That's why your example works.

Comment: `where T : IComparable<T>` is a generic constraint which requires T to be implement `IComparable<T>` (`MyClass` class doesn't required to implement `IComparable`). The `Value1` will throw NRE if it's null, strongly advised to use null-checking operator or if-condition.

Comment: I understood yes. Thank you. I mistake this with class Interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `T`, but not `MyClass<T>` that *must* implement `IComparable<T>`:

```
 where T : IComparable<T> // <- It is T that's restricted
```

In your case:

```
 // T == int; int is comparable (implements IComparable<int>)
 MyClass<int> mcInt = ...

 // T == string; string is comparable (implements IComparable<string>)
 MyClass<string> mcString = ...
```

You'll have a compile time error if you put, say, `MyClass<int[]>` (`int[]` doesn't implement `IComparable<int[]>`)

**Edit:** There're some issues with your current implementation:

```
// Technically, you don't want any MyClass<T> instance
//TODO: change into static: public static void GetBiggerValue(T Value1, T Value2
public void GetBiggerValue(T Value1, T Value2) {
  //DONE: Value1 can well be null; Value1.CompareTo(...) will throw exception then
  //DONE: CompareTo can be expensive, compute it once
  int compare = (null == Value1) 
    ? (null == Value2 ? 0 : -1) // null equals to null, but less any other value
    : Value1.CompareTo(Value2);

  // A shorter alternative is 
  // int compare = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(Value1, Value2);

  //DONE: if ... else if is more readable construction in the context 
  if (compare > 0) 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is bigger than {1}", Value1, Value2);
  else if (compare < 0)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is smaller than {1}", Value1, Value2);
  else  
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is equal to {1}", Value1, Value2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In

```
 public class MyClass<T> where T : IComparable<T>
```

the `MyClass` type does not implement (or 'inherit') `IComparable<T>` but it demands that its Type Parameter `T` does.

And in your test case, the types `int` and `string` are the ones that satisfy this constraint.